# Capture multiple lines of text after a header

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression so I can obtain the texts after a specific Header. The numbers on lines after a header are random. Also the names of the Header2 and the Header3 are unknown.
The thing is that I need to capture only the texts after the Header1, because there are similar texts after other headers that shoudn't be captured.
I was trying the following:

```
Header1\n(?:\s{4}(.+\:\s+.*)){1} //Captures -->  a:   fileAa2
Header1\n(?:\s{4}(.+\:\s+.*)){2} //Captures --> b:   fileB-
Header1\n(?:\s{4}(.+\:\s+.*)){3} //Captures --> cb:  fileCl
```

But I have to manually change the number between the curly braces... so maybe you can help me to find a better way, the text is like the following:

```
Header1
    ab:  fileAa2
    b:   fileB-
    cb:  fileCl
    ab:  fileD'
    b:   fileFn
Header2
    ab:  fileAa2
    a:   .file2
    ab:  file3/a
    a:   file4
    x:   file5
Header3
    LL
    pkg
    e
    f
```

The goal that I want to archive is to have an array like the following using a regular expression with match or exec:

```
[ab:  fileAa2,  b:   fileB-, cb:  fileCl, ab:  fileD', b:   fileFn]
```

and after that I'll filter the data by prefix like these:

```
[fileAa2, fileD']
[fileB-, fileFn]
[fileCl]
```

Please, any suggestion is welcome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help if you have trouble with the markdown, e.g. newlines. Don't worry about your English, it is good enough and better than some.

Comment: Please show some coding context, i.e. the code in which you want to use the regex. Sometimes it is easier to use some code around a pure regex, especially when looking at multiline matches. Maybe make something like a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, thank you for your observations

Comment: Do the lines to match reliably end in a newline? Or is it possible that the last line of Header1 also is the very last line in the file and is not followed by a newline? The currently accepted answer for example will fail for the last line in the file without a newline at the end.

Comment: I'm trying to filter the output of `git status` so there are kind of headers and after that the data that I want to obtain, I have just verified and It's not the last line, but I really appreciate your observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this regex (which I came up with and tested using the demo page by npinti, thanks)

```
Header1\n((\s.+\n)+\s.+[^\n])
```

you can change `Header1` for `Header2` or `Header3` and it will also work.

Also, this even works if the lines to match are at the very end of what you are processing, even without a final newline.

It assumes that the lines to match
start with whitespace (`\s.+`)
end in newline(`\n`),
possibly multiple times(`+`),
with a last line at the end starting in whitespace (`\s.+`)
but ending in someting else than newline (`[^\n]`).

The last bit avoids matching into the next header (which start with letters instead of whitespace) and gets the very last line, if it is part of the target header.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at something like this: `Header1\n(((.+?:\s+.+?)\n)+)`(example [here](https://regex101.com/r/iNyTUN/1))

Given the following text:

```
Header1
    ab:  fileAa2
    b:   fileB-
    cb:  fileCl
    ab:  fileD'
    b:   fileFn
Header2
    ab:  fileAa2
    a:   .file2
    ab:  file3/a
    a:   file4
    x:   file5
Header3
    LL
    pkg
    e
    f
```

It should match:

```
ab:  fileAa2
b:   fileB-
cb:  fileCl
ab:  fileD'
b:   fileFn
```

The expression will basically look for all the : pairs following `Header1`. Having the name of the header breaks this pattern, so the expression returns with what you want (discarding the rest of the content).

Comment: That is a working and demonstrated answer. Why use the weak "should"? It DOES match as shown for the sample input given.